# Store XML explain plan in PostgreSQL database

Tags: xml, plpgsql, postgresql-9.1, explain

How can I store XML explain plan (or any other format) in PostgreSQL database?

Test data: `explain (verbose, format xml) select 1`

Table to store results: `create table tmp.explain_plan_data (expp xml);`

My naive test failed:

```
insert into tmp.explain_plan_data values (explain (verbose, format xml) select 1);
```

It seems that explain cannot be used in any other `select` statement, the following statement does not work either:

```
select * from (explain (verbose, format xml) select 1) a
```

We are using PostreSQL 9.1.6

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not possible to capture `EXPLAIN` output using subqueries, you should go for a PL/pgSQL procedure:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION explain_v_xml(in_sql text)
RETURNS TABLE(explain_line xml) AS $explain_v_xml$
BEGIN
    RETURN QUERY EXECUTE 'EXPLAIN (VERBOSE, FORMAT xml) '||in_sql;
END;
$explain_v_xml$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Now you can query it like this:

```sql
SELECT explain_line FROM explain_v_xml('SELECT * FROM pg_locks');
```

And insert into your target table:

```sql
INSERT INTO tmp.explain_plan_data SELECT explain_v_xml('SELECT 1');
SELECT * FROM tmp.explain_plan_data;
```

Perhaps explain output alone in the table is not so handy, I would rather added
original query and `timestamptz` of the insert.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not 100% sure, but I think this only possible using a stored procedure. You could use the DO statement:

```
DO
$$
DECLARE
    _result xml;
BEGIN
    EXECUTE 'explain (verbose, format xml) select 1' INTO _result;

    INSERT INTO tmp.explain_plan_data(expp) VALUES(_result);
END;
$$;
```