# Collecting large statistical sets with pg_stat_statements?

Tags: performance, postgresql

According to Postgres [pg_stat_statements](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/pgstatstatements.html) documentation:

> The module requires additional shared memory proportional to
>   pg_stat_statements.max. Note that this memory is consumed whenever the
>   module is loaded, even if pg_stat_statements.track is set to none.

and also:

> The representative query texts are kept in an external disk file, and
>   do not consume shared memory. Therefore, even very lengthy query texts
>   can be stored successfully. However, if many long query texts are
>   accumulated, the external file might grow unmanageably large.

From these it is unclear what the actual memory cost of a high `pg_stat_statements.max` would be - say at 100k or 500k (default is 5k). Is it safe to set the levels that high, would could be the negative repercussions of such high levels? Would aggregating statistics into an external database via logstash/fluentd be a preferred approach above certain sizes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***1.***

from what I have read, it hashes the query and keeps it in DB, saving the text to FS. So next concern is more expected then overloaded shared memory:

> if many long query texts are accumulated, the external file might grow
>   unmanageably large

the hash of text is so much smaller then text, that I think you should not worry about extension memory consumption comparing long queries. Especially knowing that extension uses Query Analyser (which will work for **EVERY** query **ANYWAY**):

> the queryid hash value is computed on the post-parse-analysis
>   representation of the queries

Setting `pg_stat_statements.max` 10 times bigger should take 10 times more shared memory I believe. The grows should be **linear**. **It does not say so in documentation**, but logically should be so.

There is no answer if it is safe or not to set setting to distinct value, because there is no data on other configuration values and HW you have. But as growth should be linear, consider this answer: "if you set it to 5K, and query runtime has grown almost nothing, then setting it to 50K will prolong it almost nothing times ten". BTW, my question - who is gong to dig 50000 slow statements? :)

***2.***

This extension already makes a pre-aggregation for "dis-valued" statement. You can select it straight on DB, so moving data to other db and selecting it there will only give you the benefit of unloading the original DB and loading another. In other words you save 50MB for a query on original, but spend same on another. Does it make sense? For me - yes. This is what I do myself. But I also save execution plans for statement (which is not a part of pg_stat_statements extension). I believe it depends on what you have and what you have. Definitely there is no need for that just because of a number of queries. Again unless you have so big file that extension can

> As a recovery method if that happens, pg_stat_statements may choose to
>   discard the query texts, whereupon all existing entries in the
>   pg_stat_statements view will show null query fields

Comment: I'm running with a large number of materialized views, hence the high `pg_stat_statements.max` requirement :) Not too worried about hard-drive space, mainly memory usage detracting from actual query performance.  > This is what I do myself.  If it's possible could you share a little more about your preferred setup and how you handled unloading the primary database from statistics collection?

Comment: the big file threat is not for hdd space, but for time it takes to parse it. try querying pg_stat_statements as superuser (reading statement form file) and as not superuser (without statements). If you have big file, time differs significantly.

Comment: what I do is a hotfix style setup - not optimal, but here it is: I have set max to 1000 (lower 5 times instead). I have a job that replicates  pg_stat_statements to other db with dblink (without query, but with it's hash), and another job that sends hash and query to different table (with FK). and another job that saves current execution plan and sends it to third table with hash (FK). this way I can compare if execution time and plan has changed over time... (Oracle has something similar built in CBO)

Comment: So basically I don't unload primary DB from statistics collection - it still collects it and does all pre-aggregation. But I use different DB to keep historical data and bigger amount of queries. Meanwhile primary collects only 1000 of them and flushes em on each "replication" hourly

Comment: How are you obtaining historical query plans for the pg_stat_statement entries btw ?

Comment: same jobs saves plan to json field. Look at the http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14747331/store-xml-explain-plan-in-postgresql-database - they use xml, but the procedure is the same. and I repeat execution to get the actual plan (VERBOSE, ANALYZE, FORMAT JSON).

Comment: Doesn't repeating the execution mean you can generate a different plan than originally executed (although with a very low probability) if stats used by the query planner have changed?

Comment: yes it does. But I did not find any "feature" that would allow me checking the execution plan of already executed statement. digging plan from logs looked inappropriate for me. `http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/auto-explain.html` saves plan to log file only. So yes - I take the risk that plan is different for actual query and for job. that is why I run it daily and even hourly