# where are slow queries logged in postgresql 9.6

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.6

I have configured the `postgresql.conf` file log the queries run more than 100ms.

Where can I see the log files in version 9.6?

I could not find that in any folders in C:\PostgreSQL\data\pg96

Comment: That's not a dedicated extra logfile. It's in the regular Postgres logfile. If you run the SQL statements `show log_directory` it will show you in which directory the logfile is stored.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it
C:\PostgreSQL\data\logs\pg96

Comment: You can use the pgbadger open source tool which will generate a html report with complete information for slowest query with query and execution duration

Comment: @PawanSharma Thank you. I will see that

Comment: @PawanSharma How can I install this tool. Only source code could found in github

Comment: use https://github.com/dalibo/pgbadger link to install...This is a open source tool

Comment: @PawanSharma. Sorry, I have limited knowledge with this kind of packages.
I could able to download the package as a zip file. The README file is explaining how it will work. BUT, how can I install this and connect to my Postgers server. 
I was originally looking for some binary files for the installation. Can you guide me how to install this package

Comment: installation steps are already mention in github pgbadger link and it  doesn't require any connection with PostgreSQL database..This tool is take the PostgreSQL Logs are parse them into html format.

Answer (score 4):

1) make sure log_statement is enabled `log_statement = 'all'`

2) check `log_destination` & `log_directory`

3) restart postgres

Answer (score 2):

I highly recommend [pg_stat_statements](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/pgstatstatements.html) extension. It collects a lot of useful stats about slowest queries.

You just have to be careful about setting `pg_stat_statements.max` because if you would try to set number of logged queries too high it can cause memory problems. But it depends on how much memory and connections you have. So it is difficult to give any unified recommendation. See here for example - [Collecting large statistical sets with pg_stat_statements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34573075/collecting-large-statistical-sets-with-pg-stat-statements)